# How can I highlight specific keywords on every appended paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z8we.png)

```
     $(` <tr class="key-empty" id="${id}" >
                                            <td   colspan="3" class="text-left keyword-td " >
                                              <div class="td_div">
                                              ${sentence.map((val, i) => `<div class="d-flex shadow_"><i class="fa fa-circle mt-1 " style="font-size: 10px;"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="m-0 text-gray font-14 fw-400 keyword-para" id="key_${i}" > ${val} </span></div>`).join("<br>")
                              }
                                              </div>
                                            </td>
                                 </tr>
                                    `).insertAfter(row);
                                   var search = keyword;
  
                                    $(".keyword-para:contains("+search+")").each(function () {
                                var regex3 = new RegExp("([' ]|^)"+search+"(?=[ ]|$|,|')", 'g');
                            
                          
                              $(this).html($(this).text().replaceAll(regex3,  `<span class='text-red'> ${search} </span>`));

                          

                            });
```

I wat to change color of all keywords that is appear on text
In jquery on api response I append the paragraphs, I want to highlight specific  keyword on every appended paragraph , but it can not work on all keyword what mistake i did on it

Comment: `(?=[ ]|$|,|')` excludes any characters between your search term and the end of the line, like a question mark. For your purposes, using word boundaries `\b` is probably sufficient. So you could build your expression like `new RegExp("\\b" + search + "\\b", 'g')`.

Comment: @oriberu, answers go down there.